# ¿Es posible asignar un caracter especial a una variable en python?

Tags: python, variables, caracteres

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de asignar el signo de "$" a una variable en python además de imprimirlo en pantalla, adjunto el fragmento de código.

```
print("Bienvenido")
value = float(input("Ingresa el precio de tu producto:")) 

while value < 0:
        value = float(input("\nIngresa el precio de tu producto:"))

print("\nSelecciona el tipo de moneda que utilizas \n 1: peso $ \n 2: dolar U$S \n")

opc = int(input())

while opc <= 0 or opc >= 3:
    print("\nHas introducido una opcion erronea, favor de intentar nuevamente:")
    opc = int(input())

if opc == 1:
  print("Peso seleccionado\n")
  currency == $ 

elif opc == 2:
  print("Dolar Seleccionado\n")
  currency == U$S

print("El costo de tu producto es de:" + str(value) + currency)
```

Comment: Creo que lo que preguntas no es "asignar un `$`", sino "usar un `$` como parte de un nombre de variable, en cuyo caso la respuesta es **no**. Si lo que quieres es asignar una letra a una variable (sea esta letra un dólar o cualquier otra) basta ponerla entre comillas: `currency = "$"`

Comment: Yo creo que lo único que necesita es saber que puede guardar strings en variables. currency = "U$S"

Comment: debe usarlo como string moneda = 'USD$'

Comment: tambien podrias revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que intentas hacer, mira que es un = y no dos ==

......

```
if opc == 1:
  print("Peso seleccionado\n")
  currency = "$"  

elif opc == 2:
  print("Dolar Seleccionado\n")
  currency = "U$S"

print("El costo de tu producto es de:" + str(value) + currency)
```

Cuando usas un = haces una asignación de los que esta a la derecha a la variable que esta a la izquierda.

Cunado usas dos == hace una evaluación, esto devuelve un valor booleano y en el código al estar en una linea solos no pasa nada con este valor booleano y se pierde.